# Back button as Menu in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a back button as menu in the left of the action bar in fragment. But I don't want the back arrow as my icon.

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

The above code line gives the back arrow symbol. Instead i want to use some custom image. Also using that custom image should get it back to its previous activity.

Comment: Are you using a toolbar?

Comment: No. I am using action bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: @SuhaylSH I voted. But due to less reputations my vote isn't visible.
If you liked or found my question appropriate, kindly upvote my question. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any reputation to mark the answer correct :) I upvoted your question ..

Comment: Attach the icon and a screenshot with your question

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ***theme*** in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_icon</item>
```

It will override the default icon. By default it uses the following id:

```
android.R.id.home
```

You can use this id to navigate back to your previous activity:

```
View homeView = getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        homeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Go back
            }
        });
```

or

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Return back to your activity!
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For more information check the official documentation at : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :)
But how to use this button to go back to the previous activity.

Comment: If you set actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true), clicking it ll take you back to parent activity.

Comment: This part you didnt mention in your question!

Comment: Anyways, Android uses android.R.id.home as the id for this button. Use this id and create an OnClick listener to navigate to your other activity!

Comment: @Rider Please mark the answer correct relative to the question asked. Thanks!